# remove leading newline from bash variable

Tags: bash

The contents of `$var` are seperated by a space, so I added a loop to output each line in `$var` seperated by a newline into `"$p"`, however at the beginning a newline is also added that I can not remove.

```
echo "$var"

S1 S2 S3

for i in $var; do p="`echo -e "$p\\n$i"`"; done
echo -e "$p"
```

**current**

```
---- newline ----
S1
S2
S3
```

**desired "$p"  ---- newline removed from variable**

```
S1
S2
S3
```

**Tried: to remove starting newline**

```
echo ${p} | tr -d '\n'

S1 S2 S3
```

Comment: Does your input start with a newline or only after the loop?

Comment: A newline is introduced after the loop. Thank you :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove leading newline you can use pattern substitution

```
$ p="\nS1\nS2\nS3"
$ echo -e "$p"

S1
S2
S3
$ echo -e "${p/\\n/}"
S1
S2
S3
```

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, you're overcomplicating this (and introducing some possible bugs along the way).

Just use `tr` to replace the spaces with newlines.

```
$ var="S1 S2 S3"
$ echo "$var" | tr ' ' '\n'
S1
S2
S3
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `echo $var | tr ' ' '\n'` to replace spaces with a new line.

This works in the cases where you have multiple spaces in the contents of `var`

```
var="S1    S2 S3"
echo $var | tr ' ' '\n'
S1
S2
S3
```

If you use `"$var"`, then you your output will have empty lines in your output which I don't think anyone would like to have.

Comment: Quote your variables! `echo "$var"`

Comment: If you have multiple spaces in the contents of var, it won't work as expected and will give you empty lines in the output.

Comment: OP's output shows single spaces, but in that case: `sed -r 's/ +/\n/g'`

Comment: Yeah, there can be multiple ways and it depends on the kind of input and the expected output.

Comment: Yeah that's true. Still I wouldn't use word splitting unless I was 100% sure `$var` would never contain globbing characters. For reference see [Shellcheck SC2086](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086)

Comment: Thank you all :)

Answer (score 1):

i'd rather remove the empty line with `sed` first,

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
var="
S1 S2 S3"

echo "$var"

sed '/^$/d' <<<"${var}" | while read i; do
  echo -n -e "[$i]"
done
```

```
S1 S2 S3
[S1][S2][S3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove a single leading newline with `${var#pattern}` variable expansion.

```
var='
S1
S2
S3'

echo "${var#$'\n'}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Parameter expansion can replace each space with a newline, rather than having to iterate over the sequence explicitly.

```
$ var="S1 S2 S3"
$ var=${var// /$'\n'}
$ echo "$var"
S1
S2
S3
```